# Toggle Switch not changing position after app language is changed using GETX package Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, translation, flutter-getx

I have a toggle switch in my app, where the user clicks to change language. I am using the [toggle_switch](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch) package in my view. My view looks like this :

```
    class Welcome extends GetView<WelcomeController> {
      final WelcomeController _controller = Get.put(WelcomeController());
      Welcome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var _toggleValue = 0.obs;
 
        return Scaffold(
          body: Obx(() => Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Toggle Value : ${_controller.selectedLanguage.value}'),
              ToggleSwitch(
                minWidth: 90.0,
                cornerRadius: 20.0,
                activeBgColors: [[Colors.cyan], [Colors.redAccent]],
                activeFgColor: Colors.white,
                inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey,
                inactiveFgColor: Colors.white,
                totalSwitches: 2,
                labels: ['English', 'Bangla'],
                onToggle: (index) {
                  print('switched to: $index');
                  changeLanguage(index);
                },
              ),
            //some other widgets
            ],
          ))
        );
      }
    
      void changeLanguage(int value) {
        if (value == 0) {
          _controller.changeLang('en');
        } else {
          _controller.changeLang('bn');
        }
      }
    
    }
```

My controller has the ***changeLang*** function which does the following:

```
class WelcomeController extends GetxController{
  var selectedLanguage = Get.locale!.languageCode.obs;

  void changeLang(String lang) {
    Locale locale = Locale(lang);
    Get.updateLocale(locale);
    selectedLanguage.value = lang;
  }
}
```

If i use the above function inside the toggles onToggle function, the toggle position does not move to the current index selected and also the color does not change but the language is changed whenever I click on English or Bangla. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign toggleValue in controller like

```
enter code here
```

Then add line in ToggleSwitch as below,

```
initialLabelIndex: _controller.toggleValue.value
```

Add update method as below

```
void  changeLanguage(int value) {
   _controller.toggleValue.value = value;
   if (value == 0) {
     _controller.changeLang('en');
   } else {
     _controller.changeLang('bn');
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To get Switch to work , `move the  setState(() {})  outside of Switch in a callback function` .

```
// Switch  Widget
    Switch( value: _toggleState,
            onChanged: _attemptChange,
            ),
    
//Callback
 void _attemptChange(bool newState) {
    setState(() {
      _toggleState = newState;
      newState ? _switchCase = 'ON' : _switchCase = 'OFF';
    });
```

> or u can use CupertinoSwitch it has  value property

```
set variable in your controller


              CupertinoSwitch(
                        value: controller.boolVal,
                        onChanged: (bool value) {
                 /// change your variable value in controller       
                  }
                );
```